# how to bind a server to different ports instead of a sing le one?

Tags: c

i am writing a tcp server code to monitor tcp/ip traffic coming to my system.
Can anyone have the idea about how to bind to different tcp ports,instead of a single port.
or can anyone ve the idea about how to do it?

expecting ideas from alll good hearts

Comment: Sure - create multiple sockets, and `bind` each to a different port. If you want more information than that, you'll have to be more specific.

Comment: Hi Wooble ....thanks for the reply.......yeah i will be........my requirement is that i want to develope a sniffer code to sniff tcp/ip traffic jus like wireshark....but i dont know how to monitor all ports ..as so many tcp/ip ports are there.....

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/), it's closer to what it sounds like you need.

Answer (score 0):

For each port you are listening on you need to prepare the data structures required to bind to that port and listen on it. You cannot listen on ALL ports -- unless you work at driver level and intercept the packets before they are dispatched to the application listening on a port. So effectively, if you will, inside your app, you will start multiple servers -- one for each port -- but once you have acquired a client connection you can share the same code for all requests coming on all ports (you are listening to).

Comment: Hi Liv......thanks for the reply.......yeah am not familiar with device driver....but as u said is it necessary to do driver programming to sniff ethernet ports....

Comment: Yeah, it is, as it's only the kernel which has access to the packet before it is dispatched to its internal structures / paths in order to reach the application listening for it. (As a side not, part of this in-kernel routing can involve security checks -- e.g. firewalling -- and the packet can be dropped.)

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to create one socket per port you want to bind.  But how this will help you to "monitor tcp/ip traffic coming to your system" I am not sure.  Probably it won't.

Comment: HiJohn.... thanks for the reply.....but how to create socket for all ports... as so much of tcp ports are there?

Comment: Yeah you're on the wrong track.  Consider libpcap as regularfry suggested.